# Regex to find first 5 digits of number and last 2 numbers have to specfic within a URL

Tags: python, regex

I would to have a regex for python to detect if the URL link is valid.

It should be detecting if the digits between a '/' and '?' has the first 5 digits be '17110' and the last 2 digits be '01' and there has to be 7 digits.

For example,

```py
mainsoup = BeautifulSoup(await r.text(),features="html.parser")
for link in mainsoup.find_all('a'),
    print(link.get('href'))

    #/announcement/171103301?user_id=0&lang=2&phone_type=0
    #/announcement/171103501?user_id=0&lang=2&phone_type=0
    #/announcement/171101401?user_id=0&lang=2&phone_type=0
    #/announcement/60110100005108?user_id=0&lang=2&phone_type=0
    #/announcement/60110100005300?user_id=0&lang=2&phone_type=0
    #/announcement/1910064?user_id=0&lang=2&phone_type=0
    #/announcement/171201811?user_id=0&lang=2&phone_type=0

    #placing links into a list
    #regex to get first 3 links as valid
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do mention your research work. What you tried?What didn't worked for you, etc. Please read [how-to-ask-question-on-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You could try `/17110\d+01\?`

Comment: @Nick that works thanks!

Comment: As stated, `/171101?` would match, but I suspect you don't want it to. Can you state that there are at least 7 digits between `'/'` and `'?'`?

Comment: That is an issue. I have edited the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
.*/17110[0-9]*01\?.*
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/17OKe1/1). It will match any characters, then `/17110`, then any zero or more digits, then `01?` and  then any text to the string end.